# Why is my pop up delayed (Swift)?

Tags: swift, popup, delay

I'm a novice Swift programmer working on his first app. As part of a simple game I execute a function (F) with the following code somewhere in the middle

```
if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"P2CompetitionPopUpId") as? P2_Competition_Pop_Up {
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("error creating P2_Competion_Pop_Up")
```

However, when I run this, the pop up doesn't happen until after the entire function (F) has executed. Why is this? And how do I get the function (F) to pause while the pop-up happens and resume after the pop-up has closed?

Comment: Show the whole function so we can better see how this is called.

Comment: The function is called when another pop up closes. I don't think the surrounding code here matters. Does it have to do with pop-ups in particular? It is such a weird thing to postpone opening the popup.

Comment: Is the code being called from the main queue?

Comment: not sure what a main queue is. This has previouslt happened: The main view controller loads, runs the load code, a button is pressed, a pop up opens modally, a button is pressed there and the pop up is dismissed, a function in the main view controlled (on pop up closed) starts running, and halfway through running finds the code above, does not run it, but finishes the rest of the function, then runs it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it into async call:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "P2CompetitionPopUpId") as? P2_Competition_Pop_Up {
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        print("error creating P2_Competion_Pop_Up")
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to change anything. Or at first it gave two error messages about implicit self. when I added "self" before "storyboard" and "present" they dissapeared.